# Mongodb Aggregate a $slice to get an element in exact position from a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, slice, aggregation-framework

I would like to retrieve a value from a nested array where it exists at an exact position within the array.

I want to create name value pairs by doing $slice[0,1] for the **name** and then $slice[1,1] for the **value**.

Before I attempt to use aggregate, I want to attempt a find within a nested array. I can do what I want on a single depth array in a document as shown below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
"a" : [ 
    4, 
    2, 
    8, 
    71, 
    21
]
}
```

I apply the following: **db.getCollection('anothertest').find({},{_id:0, a: {$slice:[0,1]}})**
and I get:

```
{
"a" : [ 
    4
]
}
```

This is fantastic. However, what if the array I want to $slice [0,1] is located within the document at **objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells**?

If I can first of all FIND then I want to apply the same as an AGGREGATE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your best bet here and especially if your application is not yet ready for release is to hold off until MongoDB 3.2 for deployment, or at least start working with a release candidate in the interim. The main reason being is that the "projection" `$slice` does not work with the aggregation framework, as do not other forms of array matching projection as well. But this has been addressed for the upcoming release.

This is going to give you a couple of new operators, being [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and even [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which can be used to address array elements by position in the aggregation pipeline.

Either:

```js
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "a": { "$slice": ["$a",0,1] }
    }}
])
```

Which returns the familiar:

```js
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
```

Or:

```js
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "a": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$a", 0] }
    }}
])
```

Which is just the element and not an array:

```js
{ "a" : 4 }
```

Until that release becomes available other than in release candidate form, the currently available operators make it quite easy for the "first" element of the array:

```js
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "a": { "$first": "$a" }
    }}
])
```

Through use of the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator after [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). But getting another indexed position becomes horribly iterative:

```js
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    // Keeps the first element
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "first": { "$first": "$a" },
        "a": { "$push": "$a" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    // Removes the first element
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$ne": [ "$first", "$a" ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},
    // Top is now the second element
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "second": { "$first": "$a" }
    }}
])
```

And so on, and also a lot of handling to alter that to deal with arrays that might be shorter than the "nth" element you are looking for. So "possible", but ugly and not performant.

Also noting that is "not really" working with "indexed positions", and is purely matching on values. So duplicate values would easily be removed, unless there was another unique identifier per array element to work with. Future `$unwind` also has the ability to project an array index, which is handy for other purposes, but the other operators are more useful for this specific case than that feature.

So for my money I would wait till you had the feature available to be able to integrate this in an aggregation pipeline, or at least re-consider why you believe you need it and possibly design around it.

Comment: Ah man, that's fantastic. I will digest, experiment and have a play. Thank you for taking the time to look through this :)

Comment: I stepped through the last one and it errors after the first section with ""exception: $redact's expression should not return anything aside from the variables $$KEEP, $$DESCEND, and $$PRUNE, but returned {if: false, then: \"keep\", else: \"prune\"}",

Comment: @MattLightbourn Serves me right for typing directly in here. The whole `"if/then/else" is meant to be wrapped in a `$cond` expression, as has been edited in.

Comment: awesome! Thanks for that, I'd love to wait until 3.2 but unfortunately, all our systems are operating on the previously considered stable version; I'm looking forward to 3.2 :) Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: is there an easier way of doing this using map_Reduce?

Comment: @MattLightbourn Well maybe, as JavaScript `.slice()` is fairly straightforward. But mapReduce output has it's own quirks and it depends on the rest of the processing you want to do. If you just want the selected elements in the output, then just use the basic `$slice` projection with `.find()`,. If you have some grander operation in mind, then it is better to [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in order to put the whole purpose in context.

Comment: Thanks @Blakes Seven. You understand my problem very well indeed. I want to create a new document with first and second elements in the same array set. I'm working through trying to get the script which gave me $first and the one that gave me $second together in the same result set. I am keen to write something which I can run to create name/value pair documents so either by mapReduce or aggregation I think. Thanks again

Comment: I've asked a separate question to take this to the next level of discovery which is taking what you have kindly provided to me and asked further questions, much appreoiated